# error: its says legacy_id is an invalid identifier

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

```
import streamlit
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
streamlit.title('Citibike station')
my_cnx = snowflake.connector.connect(**streamlit.secrets["snowflake"])
my_cur = my_cnx.cursor()
my_cur.execute("select legacy_id from citibike_status") <-- error
my_catalog = my_cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(my_catalog) streamlit.write(df)
```

if I try * it fetches all the data but when I mention any of the col names it says it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it was quoted during table creation and should be accessed as such:

```
select "legacy_id" from citibike_status
```

In Python:

```
my_cur.execute("""select "legacy_id" from citibike_status""")
```

[Double-quoted Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#double-quoted-identifiers)

> If an object is created using a double-quoted identifier, when referenced in a query or any other SQL statement, the identifier must be specified exactly as created, including the double quotes. Failure to include the quotes might result in an Object does not exist error (or similar type of error).

Comment: when i try double quotes it says invalid syntax and when i try single quotes it returns legacy_id printed multiple times

Comment: @misa "when i try double quotes it says invalid syntax " - then the Python code is incorrect. I have provided sample how to use it `my_cur.execute("""select "legacy_id" from citibike_status""")`